# How to use an anonymous function to solve Stirling series n! using MATLAB

Tags: computer-science, matlab

I want to be able to use Stirling Series to approximate n! inputing a vector. So far, I can do this entry wise. And I'm not sure why I cannot input a vector.

```
F = @(n) sqrt(2.*pi.*n).*(n/exp(1)).^n .* (12.*n+1)/(12.*n)

>> F(1), F(2), F(3), F(4)
ans =
   0.998981759637105
ans =
   1.998962866134357
ans =
   5.998326524438801
ans =
  23.995887114828559
```

When I try

```
n = [1:6]
F(n)

n =
     1     2     3     4     5     6
ans =
     3.226859511810607e+02
```

I would like to get the solution of

```
F(n) 
ans =
0.9990 1.9990 5.9983 23.9959 119.9862 719.9404
```

Can someone offer some advice?

Answer (score 1):

You are not using [right array division](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rdivide.html). Using "/" instead of "./" yields to a single scalar.

Change your function handle to

> F = @(n) sqrt(2.*pi.*n).*(n./exp(1)).^n .* (12.*n+1)./(12.*n)

For the input

> n=[1:6]

we then get

> ans = 0.9990     1.9990     5.9983    23.9959   119.9862   719.9404

as desired.